# Where 2 separate columns are in a nested query

Tags: sql, db2

[image]I am writing SQL filters and have limited space within the `User_Condition` so I am wondering if it is possible to use an OR before the Nested Query I am running.

Here is an example of the base code that works and an example of what I think I am trying to accomplish.

```
select * 
from tlorder 
where detail_line_id = '3806526'
  and (origpc in (select zone_id 
                  from zone 
                  where (zone_id = origpc 
                    and service_type = 'DIRECT' or zone_id = destpc 
                    and service_type <> 'DIRECT'))
   or desctpc in (select zone_id  
                  from zone 
                  where (zone_id = origpc and service_type = 'DIRECT' or 
                         zone_id = destpc and service_type <> 'DIRECT')))
```

Starting with the and clause is the filter value but I am wondering if there is any options for something like this:

```
select * 
from tlorder 
where detail_line_id = '3806526'
  and (origpc OR destpc) in (select zone_id 
                             from zone 
                             where (zone_id = origpc and service_type = 'DIRECT' or 
                                    zone_id = destpc and service_type <> 'DIRECT'))
```

-- Note I cannot edit the highlighted section so that poses the biggest issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( 
    origpc IN (SELECT zone_id FROM zone 
    WHERE (  (
            zone_id = origpc 
            AND service_type = 'DIRECT' 
            )
            OR
            (
            zone_id = destpc 
            AND service_type <> 'DIRECT'
            )
          )
    OR destpc IN (SELECT zone_id FROM zone 
    WHERE (  (
            zone_id = origpc 
            AND service_type = 'DIRECT' 
            )
            OR
            (
            zone_id = destpc 
            AND service_type <> 'DIRECT'
            )
          )
    )
```

Based on your screen shot this should work.

Comment: This wont work unfortunately, The select statement and tables for the filter are set in stone so you can only edit after Where X = X And..... I will add a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry I am miss understanding....What makes them set in stone? The logic I provided is the same as yours just executed in a cleaner way.

Comment: I hope this is not too long.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is add the limiting logic to the where clause of your subquery and change your IN to an EXISTS.  In fact you've already almost done this because of how you're filtering the rows in your subquery.  This should work for you:

```
select * 
  from tlorder 
 where detail_line_id = '3806526'
   and EXISTS (select 1
                 from zone 
                where (zone_id = origpc and service_type = 'DIRECT') or 
                      (zone_id = destpc and service_type <> 'DIRECT')
               )
```

Note that you can select any value inside the exists I just use 1 because it's simple and won't slow anything down.  Also I made the parentheses inside your where subquery more specific.

To answer your specific question, no it's not possible to use multiple columns on the left side of an IN statement.  However, it is possible on the right hand side of an IN when you aren't using a subquery.  Example:

```
select * 
  from tlorder 
 where detail_line_id = '3806526'
   and 123 in (origpc, destpc)
```